# Probability in Poisson Process

Tags: poisson-process

Let $ {N(t)}$ be a Poisson process with $\lambda$ parameter. Let $t \in [0,T]$.

What is the probability that number of jumps in Poisson process at first half of $[0,T]$ interval will be greater than the number of jumps at second half of this interval provided that there were $n$ jumps at $[0,T]$ interval.

My attempt:

I came up with this idea:
  [image]
But $N(0) = 0$ , then we have $N(\frac{1}{2} T) > N(\frac{1}{2} T)$ which is clear non-sense.
Where is the catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0\leqslant k\leqslant n$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(N(T/2) = k\mid N(T)=n) &= \frac{\mathbb P(N(T/2)=k, N(T)=n)}{\mathbb P(N(T)=n)}\\
&= \frac{\mathbb P(N(T/2)=n, N(T)-N(T/2)=n-k}{\mathbb P(N(T)=n)}\\
&= \frac{(e^{-\lambda T/2}(\lambda T/2)^k/k!)(e^{-\lambda T/2}(\lambda T/2)^{n-k}/(n-k)!)}{e^{-\lambda T}(\lambda T)^n/n!)}\\
&= \binom nk \left(\frac12\right)^n.
\end{align}
Hence
$$
\mathbb P(N(T/2) > N(T) - N(T/2) \mid N(T)= n) =  \left(\frac12\right)^n\sum_{k=\lceil n/2\rceil}^n \binom nk.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Attempt number 2:
[image]

It looks better to me, but i am still not sure about my way of thinking.